# how to use libtomcrypt API in C and perform benchmark tests on it

Tags: c, api, aes, static-libraries, benchmarking

I have downloaded libtomcrypt API and wanted to perform benchmark testing for AES algorithm. What I have done is created a source file and included tomcrypt.h header. Then I wrote the code for testing the encryption function-"rijndael_ecb_encrypt".

```
    #include <time.h>
    #include <tomcrypt.h>   
    #define MIN_TIME 10.0
    #define MIN_ITERS 20

    double test_rijndael_ecb_encrypt(const unsigned char *pt, unsigned char *ct, symmetric_key *skey) {
        int iterations = 0;
        clock_t start;
        double elapsed=0.0;
        int out;
        start=clock();

        do{
            out = rijndael_ecb_encrypt(pt, ct, skey);
            iterations++;
            elapsed=(clock()-start)/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        } while(elapsed<MIN_TIME || iterations<MIN_ITERS);

        elapsed=1000.0*elapsed/iterations;

        printf("%s \n",pt);
        //printf("%s \n",skey->data);
        printf("%s \n",ct);
        printf("iterations: %8d \n",iterations);
        printf("%8.2lf ms per iteration \n",elapsed);
        printf("out: %d \n",out);

        return elapsed;
    }

int main(){
//called the function
}
```

It compiles correctly but there is rumtime linkage error. And it is not detecting the function "rijndael_ecb_encrypt" and shows the error as:

```
gcc  -o "TestC"  ./src/TestC.o   
./src/TestC.o: In function `test_rijndael_ecb_encrypt':
/home/anvesh/workspace/TestC/Debug/../src/TestC.c:35: undefined reference to `rijndael_ecb_encrypt'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [TestC] Error 1
```

Am I doing correct implementation for testing the executing time for the AES encryption? If not is there any alternative to implement that?? Any suggestions? Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install tom crypt library.

```
sudo apt-get install libtomcrypt-dev
```

Then include the library when compiling:

```
gcc file.c -ltomcrypt
```

Comment: just wanted to know which version of the library does the command installs? latest version??

Comment: That depends which linux(debian) you use. But you can check it when installing it. When you install it, it'll display the version of libtomcrypt. You can also look at the installed library directory to see the version. On my Ubuntu 12 `cat /usr/lib/pkgconfig/libtomcrypt.pc` shows the version as `1.17`.